# Handling refresh token by recall same request after refreshing the token

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a common interceptor to authorize all my outgoing requests.

My logic is as follows:

All my outgoing requests/API calls passes through the interceptor first to check on my token expiry and in-case the response was un-authorized I make an internal call to refresh the token and update my storage keys with the new values.

Now I need to recall the original request with the new token value, but I can't figure out how to detect the original request that passed through the interceptor.

This is my code :

```
export  const unregister =  fetchIntercept.register({
  request: function (url, config) {
    return [url, config];
  },

  requestError: function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
  responseError: function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },

  response: function (response) {
    if (response.status == 401) {
      Services.refreshToken((res)=>{
        if (res.message == 'success') {
          // if token has been refreshed
          // recall the request again
        }else {
          // login again
        }
      })
    }else {
      return response;
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is that I've no idea how to recall the same request that passed through the interceptor.. I did some search on this, but couldn't find a way to execute this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch-intercept doesn't seem to provide the original url on your response, so indeed you cannot retrigger your request.

The [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) network library also allows to register a response interceptor, and additionally provides info on the original request url:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, async apiError => {
if (
  apiError.response &&
  apiError.response.status === 401 &&
  apiError.config
) {
  try {
    // refresh access token
    const res = await Services.refreshToken();
    if (res.message === 'success') {
      const { config: oldRequest } = apiError;
      // retrigger old request
      axios.request({...oldRequest, headers: {},});
    } else {
     // go to login page.
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // refresh failed, return to login page
  }
}
```